# WPF custom control lost its event subscriptions

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I've created a complex custom control which contains some basic WPF control and an another custom control. In its OnApplyTemplate, I subscribe to several events. It works as I expected. 
But if I place this custom control into a TabControl with two tabs (the custom control is in the first tab and I switched to the second one then back to the first tab), the event subscriptions are lost. The debugger doesn't break on the event listeners.
Why these event subscriptions are lost after switching tabs in tabcontrol?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You would have to show us the relevant parts of your code. Otherwise we'd need a crystal ball to find out where you went wrong.

Comment: The loaded event of your custom control fires every time you click on that tab. I think there could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks user1994514! That was the problem! Please answer my question  so I can mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loaded event of your custom control fires every time you click on that tab. I think there could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that idea! That is where the problem was.